# Meteor does not load in Samsung Galaxy mini

Tags: android, meteor, samsung-mobile

I recently built my first app using meteor.js. It works reasonably well in all mobile devices except Samsung Galaxy Mini, in which the page does not load.

Any clues on what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Galaxy Mini is a 3 year old device running Android 2.2. It's a low-dpi device, only has 384MB RAM and a slow CPU.

Any of those might cause a problem. Did you check the Logcat of the device when you started the app? Does it give you some useful information?

If it works on all other devices, and the logcat doesn't contain any useful information, I shouldn't bother too much. It's not a popular device, and it's running 3 year old software.